# need to rewrite this query without using a correlated subquery

Tags: python, mysql

I know how `correlated subqueries` work and usually steer away from them.. but for what I was trying to do i couldn't find another way to write this query. I was ok with using it because I didn't have a bunch of records in the table I was using.. but now I need to do the same thing on some tables with > 100,000 records in them which will make this query take a long time. so I need some help with rewriting this query.

**INITIAL QUERY:**

```
SELECT
DATE(m.Created_At) AS m_date,
COUNT(m.id) AS daily_count,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(m1.id)
    FROM members_joined m1
    WHERE m1.has_verified = 1 and DATE(m1.Created_At) <= m_date
) AS member_totals
FROM members_joined AS m
WHERE m.has_verified = 1 and m.Created_At BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY m_date;
```

what this query is doing is getting the total count of registered members up to 30 days ago.. and then for every day between the last 30 days its doing the total count again

```
m_date      daily_count member_totals
2014-05-27      4           619
2014-05-29      1           620
2014-05-30      3           623
2014-06-02      4           627
2014-06-03      7           634
2014-06-04      10          644
2014-06-05      12          656
2014-06-06      4           660
2014-06-07      3           663
2014-06-08      3           666
2014-06-09      3           669
2014-06-10      5           674
2014-06-11      3           677
```

if you notice it is **incrementing** the count by **each** daily count.

this query itself only takes .036 seconds to run which isnt a big deal

but on some of the bigger tables it already takes 12 seconds and they are only going to get bigger.

**NOTE:** can this be done without using a correlated subquery? assume you cannot use user-defined variables.

if this cant be done in mysql I can hit the database twice and do it in python, but I was hoping to find a solution in MySQL and not hit the database multiple times.

thanks for any pointers / help!

Comment: How about using a stored procedure? In the first step you store the start value in a variable. This is one single query (of your inner ones) and should be fast, assuming an index on created_at. Then you use your outer query in combination with this variable or even a cursor (it's only 30 rows) on the current outer query.

Comment: well i made a few methods to hit the database.. im using scalars here for this question as its returning multiple rows. I don't know if I can call a stored procedure with this method though... and if thats the case it would probably be faster to just do the calculations in python itself.. bleh

Comment: I am sorry, I did miss the note about UDV. Then you can just take data for each day and the init count, and compute the third column in python. You will need a single query.

Comment: @newtover put your answer back up lol

Comment: I have put my answer back, but it still does not match your question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can hardly be done with pure SQL efficiently, but you can use MySQL-specific user defined variables. You will just need to compute counts for each day and accumulate counts for each row.

The main trick is to force MySQL update the variable in the correct order.

The query should look like the following (not sure that it is 100% correct):

```
SELECT m_date, daily_count, @count:=(daily_count + @count) as member_totals
FROM
(SELECT DATE(Created_At) as m_date, COUNT(*) as daily_count
 FROM members_joined
 WHERE DATE(Created_At) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND has_verified = 1
 GROUP BY m_date
) as days,
(SELECT @count:=COUNT(*) as cnt0
 FROM members_joined
 WHERE DATE(Created_At) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
   AND has_verified = 1) as init
ORDER BY m_date;
```

Comment: I don't know if you noticed or not, but using user-defined variables is something I said I can't do... they don't work with our system. see the NOTE: in my question --- aside from that this would work a LOT faster

Comment: I would have already done that if i could use them :(... unfortunately i can't... i'll have to go with two hits on the database and do the calculations in python i guess

Comment: @John, but why do you need two hits?

Comment: to put things into perspective i wrote this exact query before posting the question and it really does speed things up.. goes from 14.347 seconds to 0.877 seconds to run... i'll do it in python and just run this query without the UDV.. accepting your answer because it does what I asked even though i can't use it :)

Comment: If i do it as two selects in one query the count is off (not by much) i haven't figured out why yet, but when I do i'll be using one hit... theres multiple levels to this though.. I have to do this type of query 10 times and then take each one and build a master list of interactions for the last 30 days.. with calculations for making things cumulative and daily.. write to excel and graph in excel... so i know exactly what the output is supposed to be but not sure why the count is about 100 off. anyways thanks for the effort!

Comment: @JohnRuddell, my guess is that you used `<=` instead of `<` in the second subquery and now have those extra 100 =)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : fix a mistake in the query

EDIT2 : proposal of a python way

You can rewrite it with an explicit auto-join, but I do not think it will be faster

```
SELECT
DATE(m.Created_At) AS m_date,
COUNT(m.id) AS daily_count,
COUNT(m1.id) AS member_totals
FROM members_joined AS m
JOIN members_joined m1 ON m1.has_verified = 1 and DATE(m1.Created_At) <= DATE(m.Created_At) 
WHERE m.has_verified = 1 and m.Created_At BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY m_date;
```

You are asking the database to get a quadratic number of rows.

As the autojoin do not improve performance, I think you should 2 simpler queries from your database, and then do the sums in Python.

```
SELECT
DATE(m.Created_At) AS m_date,
COUNT(m.id) AS daily_count,
FROM members_joined AS m
WHERE m.has_verified = 1 and m.Created_At BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY m_date;
```

to get daily_count per date for the last 30 days, and

```
SELECT
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AS m_date,
COUNT(m.id) AS member_totals,
FROM members_joined AS m
WHERE m.has_verified = 1 and m.Created_At < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

to get the cumulative member_totals for the day preceding the first of the other query

Python pseudo code, say second query initialized `member_total`, and then first query initialized rows (be it a cursor or a list or tuple obtained by `fetchall`)

```
for row in rows:
    dat, daily_count = row
    member_totals += daily_count
    # use dat, daily_count, member_totals
```

Comment: have you tried this before? it returns an error because it doesn't know what the column m_date is.. Unknown column 'm_date' in 'on....

Comment: I made it work... did a SELECT of the m_date and daily_count, then joined on the outer select so it has m_date as a column... takes 2 seconds longer.. since this question is about performance this does the opposite of what I want :(

Comment: @JohnRuddell Sorry for the mistake. No, I could not test without the table... Post edited

Comment: well... i did that change... not sure how this is that different but now instead of 14 seconds its taking 83 seconds lol...